# How to use condition with lists in Terraform 11

Tags: terraform

I need to create a condition in terraform 11 where I check if a local list variable exists, if it does then use that list and if not use a different one.

For example, I have:

```
var.localList = ["apples", "oranges"]

var.remoteList = ["bananas", "carrots"]
```

Now I want to do something like this (which didn't work):

```
myVar = ["${length(var.localList) > 0 ? var.localList : var.remoteList}"]
```

So the idea is that if `var.localList` is not empty, assign that list to `myVar`, otherwise use `var.remoteList`.

Not sure if this is possible in Terraform 11.

EDIT: Forgot to mention that I'm using terraform 11.

Comment: Can you post your resource block? what exactly you wanted to do with the result list?

Answer (score 3):

You could do this with [Local Values](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/locals.html):

```
variable "local_list" {
  default = ["foo"]
}

variable "remote_list" {
  default = ["bar"]
}

locals {
  myvar = length(var.local_list) > 0 ? var.local_list : var.remote_list
}

# myvar value is "foo"
output "myvar" {
  value = local.myvar
}
```

Comment: That example in the answer works for me as expected. Are you doing something different? If so you should edit your question to show exactly what you've tried in a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

The function `coalescelist` seems to do exactly what you want.

From [the docs](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/coalescelist.html)

> coalescelist takes any number of list arguments and returns the first one that isn't empty.

So you would write something like

```
myVar = coalescelist(var.localList, var.localList)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer here https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/18259

Basically it's a work-around at this point

```
myVar   = "${split(",", length(var.localList) > 0 ? join(",", var.localList) : join(",", var.remoteList))}"
```

Comment: Are you using Terraform 0.11 or lower? If so you should have explained that in your question because Terraform 0.12 would properly handle those lists that's in the other answer and has now been out for more than 9 months so it's pretty reasonable to expect that people are using 0.12 unless they specifically state otherwise.